# C++ SFML Pointing/Rotating rectangle towards mouse position

Tags: math, rotation, sfml, rectangles

In my program there is a local sprite in the center of the screen, and I am trying to create a RrectangleShape, pointed at the mouse when left click is pressed. I have all of that figured out except for how to point the rectangle towards the mouse.

Thanks in advance,
CowNation

Comment: You want to look at some 2D vector math here. Create a vector for the mouse click position, and a vector for your rectangle origin (use `getPosition()`). Then `mouseClickPos - rectangle_.getPosition()` will give you a vector pointing from your rectangle to the mouse. You need to convert this to an angle. There are plenty of good resources on the 'net for these types of calculations.

Comment: Do you mean something like a compass?